# Sinalização por erro tipográfico / problema que não pode ser reproduzido

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, sinalização

Acredito que seria útil incluir nas sinalizações o equivalente ao

> **Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic**  This question was caused by a
>   **problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here,
>   this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.
>   This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the
>   shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

do SOEN, acredito que perguntas como esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21934/importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-pacote-gnu-io se encaixam na descrição e seria um motivo um pouco mais justo que:

**Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programação)**  e

**This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**

Comment: Eu gosto dessa do erro tipográfico. Transformar o SOpt num catálogo de erros de sintaxe é pontual demais. E já está acontecendo.

Comment: "Pontual demais" é uma excelente tradução de *too localized*.

Comment: Também acho interessante.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que fazer com perguntas que apenas procuram “code review for typos”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514/3117)

Comment: Foi inserido um novo motivo que contempla o seu pedido: _Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável._

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que este seu comentário serveria de resposta. (não sei se é o objetivo do meta ter uma porcentagem de respostas) ou se a tag [tag:status-pronto] basta.

Comment: É que o Gabe que fez, por conta própria. Ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1963